# coldfusion after screen size detection

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, screen, detection, responsive-design

I am making a responsive website and I want to be able to use javascript to get the screen size and then render a coldfusion include depending on the screen size. Something like this:

```
if (screen.width <= 700) {
     <cfinclude template="file1.cfm">
} else {
     <cfinclude template="file.cfm">
}
```

I've also tried loading via .ajax() but I get stuck when I have include files inside the cfm file in already want to include.

Comment: Do file.cfm and file1.cfm include HTML or JavaScript as their output content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. JavaScript is a client side language, ColdFusion is a server side language. You cannot do a cfinclude in a block of JavaScript as that code will be executed in the browser, not on the server.

Comment: I know the code doesn't work but I've tried loading the cfm file via .ajax() but that didn't work either if there is a secondary include file in the file I want to include so I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Actually, it is possible.  Take a look at my answer and see if you disagree.

Comment: meijiOrO - As I see it, you have three viable options.

1. Use Evik's solution involving a redirect.

2. Use media queries - http://bit.ly/moVx2X

3. Use something in Application.cfc to check for the user agent and set a variable to determine what file to include. I know, this will not take into account the screen size, but based on your other requirements, this method may meet more of your requirements than any other. Here is more info on how to do that, http://bit.ly/xNiNP3

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript is client side. ColdFusion is server side. If you want to mix the two, you need Ajax. You should try something more like using jQuery for easy Ajax:

```
// LOOK AT THE SCREEN WIDTH
if (screen.width <= 700) {
     // LOAD THE PAGE INTO THE CORRECT SIZED DIV
     $("#YourDiv").load("ColFusionFile-01.cfm");
} else {
     // LOAD THE PAGE INTO THE CORRECT SIZED DIV
     $("#YourDiv").load("ColFusionFile-02.cfm");
}
```

Or, you might want to redirect them:

```
// LOOK AT THE SCREEN WIDTH
if (screen.width <= 700) {
     // SEND THE VISITOR TO THE CORRECT SIZED PAGE
     window.location.href = "ColFusionFile-01.cfm"
} else {
     // SEND THE VISITOR TO THE CORRECT SIZED PAGE
     window.location.href = "ColFusionFile-02.cfm"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect. I just want to append to the template. I also tried using .load() but the include file has mysql queries and other includes and variables in it.

Comment: Given the specific way the question is worded, "use javascript to get the screen size and then render a coldfusion include depending on the screen size", this is the closest answer to date.  In order the determine the screen size, the page has to complete and render so JS can fire to get the size.  Then, based on the size, it's making a new request to the appropriate CF file.  Granted, it's not as an include, but the correct CFM file is going to be called.  If that file needs to do other things, great, pass it the info it needs to do those things on the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using CSS media queries and stylesheets for different display rendering based on screen size. This will allow you to have one CF page for both displays.  No AJAX needed.

W3C documentation on Media Queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Great article on "Responsive Web Design":
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Here are some awesome examples of sites that use this technique:http://mediaqueri.es/